# Is it a good approach to use Transaction controller in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-transactions

We are performing load testing using JMeter, we have to calculate the time taken by each page, but each page has multiple requests. Should we add transaction controller to find out the overall time taken by each page or should we calculate time taken by each sample in JMeter?

Comment: Please Refer: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31784/jmeter-simple-controller-and-transaction-controller

Comment: Thank you @Yugal . I have started using transaction controller , but response time for trsanction controller is huge. Ex: I have to find the response time for each page, but each page contains multiple http sample requests(10-12). If i use transaction controller , it shows sum of all samples request time than average time taken by each sample which will be like 120000ms (120sec). But manually application takes hardly 3sec for one page to load

Comment: There are multiple things, when you talk about page load time, and request time for each request within a page, which may be synchronous or asynchronous.
You also need to consider "DOMContentLoaded" vs "LoadTime" for a page, which cannot be explained by Jmeter.
These timestamps also depends on the network speed.

Refer: 
1) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation
2) http://webpagetest.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) isn't the case,it should be used to group **several** samplers

> Transaction Controller generates an additional sample which measures the overall time taken to perform the nested test elements.